# Example of utility functions

Tags: functions, economics

I am working on an Economics problem and an example function of a graph that looks like this would be helpful. Suppose the straight line is $ax + by = c$, and the curvy lines (called [Indifference Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indifference_curve)) are given by the (utility) function $U(x,y)$ when constant.

I need example functions $U(x,y)$ which, when constant, look like the curvy lines.

Note that $t > s > r$.

[image]

Comment: I think it has something to do with an transformed quartic function. To me it doesn´t look like a trigonometric function. Anyway it seems that you are satisfied with the given answer.

Comment: @callculus42 It can be anything, essentially. All I needed was a function that can give me tangency points like that. You example works too, but I didn't know how to rotate the quartic.

Comment: So you're fine with the trigometric function?

Comment: @callculus42 Yes. But if you wish to give another, sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experiment with

$$
u(x,y) =  r\sin\left(s x\right)\ - tx -y
$$

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you. Can I ask this as well - If I set the Lagrangian as $\mathcal{L} = U(x,y) - \lambda (c - ax - by)$, will I get all three tangential points that intersect the straight line or just the two that belongs to $U(x,y) = s$? (Note that $t > s > r$ which I have just added to the post.)